# Which program supports export (PDF/LaTex) to show full tree, not only ancestors/decendants

Tags: software-recommendations, gramps, chart-type, non-blood-relative

I'm currently using gramps (5.0.2) to build my family tree.

I wanted to generate a report of a relative and the report should include basically everything, well at least it should include his grandparents and also the siblings of his grandparents and so on.

But all reports I can find only ever include the direct relatives (blood line), siblings of ancestors (and their own ancestors/descendants) are not included.

I also tried other apps like "Ahnentafel" or "Family Tree Maker" but none seem to have such reports, it always is Ancestors, Decendants or Hour Glass. The only program I found which achieved what I want is "Stammbaumdrucker" but it looks a bit complex for my taste (overkill for my purpose) and I would rather continue working with Gramps only so it would be great if there maybe would be some report for it that does what I need.

Any ideas if there is such a report in Gramps or maybe in a freeware alternative?

Comment: Just to clarify - this has been marked up as "non blood relative". However, siblings of ancestors and their children are blood relatives to the root in my book. So is the desire for a report on all blood relatives, including cousins several times removed? (And what about their spouses?) Or is the desire for a report covering all the linked people? (e.g. children of parents of spouses of blood relatives) Or do you want a report to cover anyone on the file, such as someone's employers?

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Of course those are also blood relatives. What I want is generally speaking a report that includes the whole database but doesn't look as ugly as the report "Reports > Graph -> Relationship graph" but looks more like "Reports -> Trees -> Ancestors"

Answer (score 2):

You could try Reports/Graph/relationship graph.  There you can choose to show the entire db or people with common ancestors with x. If you want to be more specific, you can create custom filters.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I forgot that report, but to be honest, I think this reports is pretty ugly. It looks like someone with 1 hour visio experience has clicked something together while drunk.
Under Reports->Trees->Ancestors or Descendants are better looking reports, but those don't have the option to include the whole tree, or maybe I'm missing an option?

Answer (score 1):

[Family Historian](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) has an everyone (in the database) diagram and it is customisable for layout and colours. Bear in mind that this can be huge if you have a lot of people in your tree. There is a 1 month free trial so you can try it to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Which one is this, do you mean the View -> Standard Diagrams -> Everyone?

Comment: Yes that's the one. There is the All Ancestors query as well that you can use as the source for a custom diagram.

Comment: Okay, hadn't much time yet to explore this app yet but saw many recommendations and good reviews for it. Will check it out it the next days and maybe it can replace gramps for me. I'd like to have a good, robust all in one solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph View addon can show all connected people and you can save it to svg file.

https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Addon:Graph_View